# Make a specific word in a paragraph a specific color

Tags: html

What I want to do is to make the word "THIS" blue without having to make a second paragraph.

```
<html>
<body>
<center>

<h3 style=font-family:Calibri;font-size:50px;>test site</h3>

<p>everything here is a regular color but i want <b>THIS</b> to be blue.</p>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Could somebody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>
<center>

<h3 style=font-family:Calibri;font-size:50px;>test site</h3>

<p>everything here is a regular color but i want <b style="color:blue;">THIS</b> to be blue.</p>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give the `<b>` tag a `class` or a `style` attribute to give it a colour, like this:

```html
<style>
.blue{
    color: blue;
}
</style>

<p>everything here is a regular color but i want <b class="blue">THIS</b> to be blue.</p>

OR

<p>everything here is a regular color but i want <b style="color: blue">THIS</b> to be blue.</p>
```

Hope this helps.